# laravel/cashier v7.0.5 requires stripe/stripe-php ~4.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I'm having a Laravel 5.5 project and trying to run this command from my terminal

```
composer require laravel/cashier
```

but I'm getting this Problem:

```
Problem 1
  - stripe/stripe-php v3.9.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.9.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.8.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.7.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.6.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.5.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.4.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- stripe/stripe-php v3.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
...
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

From a google research I did I tried `sudo apt-get install php-curl` as one possible solution, but didn't work for me.

Anyone know how can I fix this issue?

**EDIT** This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Install curl and restart your web server and see if you success or not. If not see next error.

Comment: No didn't work for me that. I already tried it but I get same error

Comment: see if ext curl is loaded or not. if not then try to load curl first because error says that

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Simply run `$php -m` command on terminal and see if the module loaded OR 


phpinfo() http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php by creating a php page on your server.

Comment: I did run `php -m` but don't have any `ext-curl` on the list. Also on `phpinfo()` the only thing I get is this `cURL  Sterling Hughes`. Is this `ext-curl` different from the one on phpinfo?

Comment: thats why I am saying try to resolve the error that laravel given to you, Try to install and load curl first. After installing curl you have to restart the server.

Comment: But I already run `sudo apt-get install php-curl` and restart apache but didn;t work

Comment: sometimes `sudo apt-get install php-curl` not enough to get curl ext working on your php. google little bit to have your curl ext installed on your php version. (Specifically for your php version)

Comment: You were right, it needed this `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl` for me. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it? thanks!

Comment: okay sure, i can do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As error message suggests you to install curl extension on your PHP. Please install curl and restart your web server.

You need to make sure that you are installing correct version of curl extension for your PHP. 
**In your case:**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

To list out the loaded extensions/modules on your php 
Run following command on your terminal

```
$ php -m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer require "laravel/cashier":"7.0"` instead of just `composer require laravel/cashier`. Laravel got updated to 5.6 so you are pulling the wrong version for 5.5

Comment: No, the Problem is still there. Also tried `composer require "laravel/cashier":"~7.0"` but no luck

Comment: can you give us your `composer.json` file?

Comment: I did an update on my post. As a side note, I did run `composer update` after `sudo apt-get install php-curl`, not sure if that caused it